# Вёрстка на флексбокс

Tags: flexbox

Во флекс-контейнере есть 3 элемента. Необходимо первые 2 элемента расположить на первой строке, 3-ий элемент на второй строке(и все по центру). Как правильно сделать, чтобы ещё и по высоте корректно отображалось. А то указываю `flex-wrap: wrap` и верх блока уходит за верхнюю часть экрана без возможности скрола.

Answer (score 0):

display: flex;
justify-content: space-around (или center); - выставляет по центру контейнеры
align-items: flex-start; - ставит их по вертикали сверху вниз
flex-flow: row wrap; - ставит контейнеры в строчку с переходом на следующую, если не хватает места
flex-row: 30px; - это отступы по горизонтали
flex-column: 30px; - это отступы по вертикали

Контейнерам задаём:
width: calc(50% - 15px);

А то что он у вас скрывается за верхнюю часть экрана, думаю у вас этот блок фиксирован по высоте и написано - overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Для решения такой проблемы необходимо использовать свойство align-items в флекс-контейнере.
Для расположения элементов в центре необходимо применить значение align-items: center. Также для корректного переноса элементов на вторую строку необходимо добавить свойство flex-wrap: wrap.
В итоге получим следующую разметку:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Элемент 1</div>
  <div>Элемент 2</div>
  <div>Элемент 3</div>
</div>

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```